# Spark java.lang.StackOverflowError on Power Iteration Clustering

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I am trying to run Spark's Power Iteration Clustering algorithm for 5000 iterations on 80 million rows of data. On low iterations (couple hundred) it finishes fine so its not a code issue. At high iteration it gives me a java.lang.StackOverflowError exception.

I know that it means that DAG grew too large and it can't keep track of the lineage etc. I also have read that checkpointing can solve this issue in iterative algorithms. The problem is that PIC has no checkpoint interval parameter like the LDA algorithm so I can't (or at least don't know how to) checkpoint in the middle of the algorithm running.

Is there another possible fix to this issue? I have also attempted to increase the stack memory but that hasn't worked. I can't decrease the iterations because it won't converge.

Comment: How did you solve it?